# SQL query with GROUPING SETS to get subtotals with a HAVING clause

Tags: t-sql, group-by, aggregate

Let's say I have a (fictional) table `City` with the following columns:

```
Country: string  
State: string 
City: string 
Population: integer
```

I want a query that shows the total population by State, by Country and overall, **excluding states below 1,000,000 inhabitants**.

```
SELECT Country, State, SUM(Population) AS [Total]
FROM   City
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( Country, State), ( Country), () )     
HAVING SUM(Population) < 1000000
ORDER  BY Country, State
```

The problem with this query is that the `Country` and `Overall` totals **will** include the population of states below 1,000,000 inhabitants (meaning the total of states doesn't match the total of its parent country).
(This is assuming that the countries have over 1,000,000 inhabitants)

How can we amend the query above to fulfill the requirements?

I'm using sql azure...

Comment: I posted a variant of this question that is more complex because it is using a non additive measure. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222799/sql-query-with-grouping-sets-to-get-subtotals-with-a-having-clause-non-additive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the "having clause"  before grouping set

```
SELECT Country, State, SUM(Population) AS [Total]
FROM
(
    SELECT Country, State, SUM(Population) AS [Population]
    FROM   City
    GROUP  BY Country, State  
    HAVING SUM(Population) > 1000000
)A
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( Country, State), ( Country), () ) 
--HAVING SUM(Population) > 1000000
ORDER BY Country, State
```

here it's a sample :

```
;with City
AS
(SELECT 'Count1' as Country,'St1' as State,'C1' as City,100 As Population Union ALL
 SELECT 'Count1', 'St1' , 'C2', 50 Union ALL
 SELECT 'Count1','St2' , 'CCC 1', 50 Union ALL
 SELECT 'Count1','St2' , 'CCC 2 ', 40 
)


SELECT Country, State, SUM(Population) AS [Total]
FROM
(
    SELECT Country, State, SUM(Population) AS [Population]
    FROM   City
    GROUP  BY Country, State  
    HAVING SUM(Population) > 100
)A
GROUP  BY GROUPING SETS ( ( Country, State), ( Country), () ) 
--HAVING SUM(Population) > 100
ORDER BY Country, State
```

output:

```
Country State   Total
                150
Count1          150
Count1  St1     150
```

dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=86caadab213cd89aa5e545b7fba372ed)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to achieve it with a single group by but I don't think this is possible.

Comment: I posted a variant of this question that is more complex because it is using a non additive measure. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222799/sql-query-with-grouping-sets-to-get-subtotals-with-a-having-clause-non-additive

Comment: @Clement, see here a try of this request https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5ecca74daf7f6ce790d1ed08e0b0f64

Comment: thank you so much @sabin-bio. Feel free to propose as an answer on the other question, I will mark it as accepted since it is more generic that the current answer. In particular your solution support grouping by multiple colums.

Comment: @Clement, ok , I posted it